# Windows 10 keeps forgetting settings

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 has lately been forgetting a bunch of settings and I haven't figured out why yet. I've tried running sfc /scannow but there were no integrity problems.

Symptoms:

1. Some startup programs don't start up even if I toggle them (e.g. Discord, Telegram, Steam...)
2. Some apps forget their settings. Windows Snipping Tool for instance always suggest an old folder I haven't saved files into in ages. And the Google Chrome web browser always opens up as a small window in the upper right portion of my screen instead of the usual size (nearly fullscreen) that I always use.

There might be other similar symptoms as well but these are extremely frequent.
I'm running Windows 10 64bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this situation do the following:  Start with the basic repair. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run both: dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth and then follow with SFC /SCANNOW When done, restart and test.

Comment: It started the earlier problems again, but I'll just redo those steps every now and then. At least it's a huge help